# Visual Studio 2013 Targeting

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, target-platform

So, I use VS 2013 and want to build WinForm application which will run on Windows XP and Windows 10. Which TargetFramework should I choose? When I set .NET Framework 2.0 Win10 says that I need .NET Framework 3.5.

Also, I didn't check scenario when I set .NET Framework 4.5 and run my app on Win XP.

Is it possible to make WinFrom app which will work on all platforms in range XP-Vista-7-8-8.1-10?

Comment: Your question is duplicate to a series of other questions. So you should dig those before coming back with a more specific one.

Answer (score 1):

As Windows XP, Vista and Windows 7 do not have any .NET Framework pre-installed, you will have to install .NET framework anyhow. 
So you can choose the highest .NET version which is compatible with Windows XP, which is .NET 4.

Edit: The last supported version is .NET 4.0.3

Comment: .NET **4.0** to be exact. from 4.5 on, .net is not supported on XP.

Comment: In fact, the official name is "Microsoft .NET Framework 4" (see [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17851)). The latest version of  "Microsoft .NET Framework 4" is 4.0.3.

Comment: Windows Vista and Windows 7 does have .NET Framework 2.x/3.x bundled. None of 4.0.x is supported any more. Microsoft only supports 4.5.2 and above.